# url do not show the form values which are send to another file

Tags: php

problem in data sending through url but it not reflect any data on other php page what is wrong in my code
 here is the code

```
  if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
         {

            $id1 = $_POST["edit_id"];
            $name1=($_POST['name']);
            $lname1=($_POST['lname']);
            $email1=($_POST['email']);
            $username1=($_POST['username']);
            $password1=($_POST['password']);
            $mobile1=($_POST['mobile']);
            $address1=($_POST['address']);
            $gender1=($_POST['gender']);



$result = file_get_contents('http://localhost/service/service.php?action=update_details&id1='.$id1.'&name1='.$name1.'&lname1='.$lname1.'&email1='.$email1.'&username1='.$username1.'&password1='.$password1.'&gender1='.$gender1.'&mobile1='.$mobile1.'&address1='.$address1);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's really difficult to tell if you don't provide the other page's code.

Let's call this code you provide Page B.

Here you are receiving POST data from another page, let's call it Page A, are you sure the page A is sending the data as a POST request to page B?

What do you see if you dump the $_POST variable in page B?

You are calling service.php (let's call it page C) from page B and sending a GET request. Are you sure you the data is read as a GET request in page C?

What do you do with var $result in page B?

Can you tell if you have problems in page A, B or C?

Additionally, you should delete the parentheses around $_POST variables. They are pointless.

Comment: Were you able to perform any of the tests I told you?